# Something like Duration.of() for data size

Tags: java

Im trying to convert file sizes in a more readable way. Is there something like

```
Duration.ofMillis(1000).toSeconds();
```

for data sizes. I want something like this:

```
Size.ofMegaBytes(5).toBytes();
```

Comment: Not in core java, no. Maybe some libraries offer that functionality.

Comment: @luk2302 A Library would be fine aswell.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic: try Googling.  However, I suspect you won't find a decent library.  One reason is that `Duration` is part of a large library for dealing with time ... which is a seriously complicated problem.  By contrast, dealing with sizes is almost too simple to write classes for.  A second is that "megabytes" is actually a rather ill-specified concept.  There are actually two meanings (10^6 and 2^20), both of which are in common usage.

Comment: I agree with you. i will probably write some own util methods. The reason i want to do this is to make the code more readable. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After longer research i found a similar class in the **spring-core** library.

```
DataSize.ofMegabytes(5).toBytes();
```

More Info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html)